# Is there a way to check which file has been taken biggest space?

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage

On my Ubuntu server the Disk Usage shows that my `/dev/xvda1` is used to 100%.
What's the best way to find the most space consuming files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `du` command, then sort the output:

```
du /some/path/ -h | sort -hr | head
```

The `-h` flag makes [`du`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/du.1.html) use human-readable output (aka using `K`,`M`, etc. suffixes instead of simply spewing bytes). The `-h` flag for [`sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sort.1.html) makes it sort such human readable numbers and `-r` sorts in reverse (descending order).

This will take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the top 10:

```
du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
```

- du is disk usage -h human readable -s summary -x skip directories
- sort, -r  to reverse the result. -h human readable numbers.
- head: show the first 10 lines. If you want more/less results change the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **NCurses Disk Usage:**

> ncdu (NCurses Disk Usage) is a curses-based version of the well-known 'du', and provides a fast way to see what directories are using your disk space.

It is available on [universe](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/ncdu) repository.

Install `ncdu` by following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

Then run `ncdu` and you will get output like following:

[image: screen0]

You can also provide path-of-directory by:

```
ncdu <path/to/dir>
```

Also helpful options like:

> -q  Quiet mode. While scanning or importing the directory, ncdu will
>              update the screen 10 times a second by default, this will be
>              decreased to once every 2 seconds in quiet mode. Use this feature
>              to save bandwidth over remote connections.

Visit man page: [**`man ncdu`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ncdu.1.html) for more further options and more information.